# Android Studio AVD Linux AMDGPU driver

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-virtual-device, amd-gpu

I'm unable to start any virtual device via AVD (Android Virtual Device Manager) on Linux using the newest open source AMD drivers AMDGPU.

- GPU: AMD Rx 460
- CPU: Intel Core i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
- OS: Solus OS
- Kernel: 4.7.4
- Mesa: 12.0.3
- AMDGPU: 1.1.1

Error message:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

The error message in screenshot form: [avd amdgpu error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhyXZ.png)

I assume that the problem is that it wants old open source drivers called RadeonSI, but my graphic card doesn't use that anymore, it uses newer AMDGPU.

Any tips how would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry I was wrong. It wasn't AMDGPU issue.

It was previously know issue with AVD bundled libraries.

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -use-system-libs
```

**Explanation**

`~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator` is the path to your SDK. You can find that inside Android Studio: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK

`Nexus_5_API_23` is your virtual device that you have to create in Android Studio. You can find the list of available devices:

`~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd -list-avds`

And last:
`-use-system-libs` uses your system libraries instead of bundled

---

The above is temporary solution. The permanent solution that I have found is a probably not that great. So use this at your own risk.

In your home directory .bashrc (hidden file) set environment variable:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/your/android/sdk`

Restart / logout.

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

Obviously make sure that `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib64/libstdc++` is the valid path. This will depend on where you extract/move your sdk directory.

After this everything was working for me.

There is another solution which looks more legit, but sadly did not work for me.

`export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1`

[Issue on Google Bug Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197254#c15)